# How to design a RF-SQUID qubit by Qiskit Metal?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

I am now learning how to use [Qiskit Metal](https://qiskit.org/documentation/metal/circuit-examples/index.html) to design superconducting circuits. I found that there are only several transmon qubits in the library. Can I design an RF-SQUID qubit by using Qiskit metal?

I am a new user here. Hope you can give me some suggestions on that.

Comment: This is a great question for the #metal Slack channel where we have active developer support You can find the Slack channel [#metal](https://qiskit.slack.com/archives/C01R8KP5WP7) in the [qiskit workspace](https://ibm.co/joinqiskitslack).